# Default formatting number in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been frustrated about this problem which is number formatting in my application which somehow use comma (`,`) separated digits instead of dot (`.`) for numbers.

In my view I have this textbox:

```
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Money,"{0:N}",new { @class="form-control" })
```

On server 1, the result would show something like this:

```
155.600,00
```

On server 2, the result is totally different:

```
155,600.00
```

The format on server 1 is the correct one, however on server 2 it won't change even if i re-deploy the app. Both server region are the same (Indonesia).

This also affects when I saved the value using format 1 on the server 2, since they will be saved different:

```
155.600 (Input) => 155,6 (Result)
```

I thought this was about the localization, so I tried adding the localization however how do I test to see if its working or not? Since I can't use the server without being on-site.

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("id-ID");
});
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Do you want to send different requests to simulate different locales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this looks like your servers are using different locales. You can either override the default request culture, or you can specify it explicitly as a request header when you make requests. I'm pretty sure the string `"id-ID"` is a placeholder, you need to put in an actual locale like `"en-US"`.

You can test this locally by setting the default locale to something different to your OS's locale, and see if it does override the string formatting as expected. If that works, then you can deploy to the server with confidence that it will use the locale specified in your application, not the locale of the server.